# Tengo un problemita para hacer que imprima los valores almacenados en a estructura

Tags: c

Bien estoy tratando de hacer un programa de maquina expendedora que pida al usuario una determinada la cantidad de productos (max 10) y precio y luego los muestra, pero no he logrado hacer que los muestre aun. el programa no posee errores corre bien hasta el punto de no mostrar los datos almacenados. señálenme mi error por favor.

Este de aqui es mi codigo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

   struct producto{

    char nombre[12];
    int precio;
}producto[12];


 int main()
 {

    // ALMACENAMOS LA CANTIDAD DE PRODUCTOS
    int cantidad;

    // GUARDAMOS DENTRO DE LA VARIABLE
    printf("\nDigite la cantidad de productos: ");
    scanf("%i", &cantidad);

    // ITERADOR PARA NUESTRO BUCLE
    int i;

    // CREAMOS UN BUCLE DE TIPO FOR PARA DARLE VALOR A LAS VARIABLES DE NUESTRA ESTRUCTURA
    for (i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
    {
        // LIMPIAR LA MEMORIA DE NUESTRO BUFFER
        fflush(stdin);


        // GUARDAMOS EL NOMBRE
        printf("\n Digite su nombre: ");
        gets(producto[i].nombre);

        // GUARDAMOS EL PRECIO
        printf("\n Digite su precio: ");
        scanf("%i" ,&producto[i].precio  );

    }

    // IMPRIMIR LOS RESULTADOS DE NUESTRA ESTRUCTURA
    for (i=1; i<cantidad; i++)
    {


    // IMPRIMIMOS TODOS LOS DATOS
  printf("\n Nombre: %s " , producto[i].nombre);
  printf("\n Precio: %i " , producto[i].precio);


    }


    system ("pause");

    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es un error muy tonto. Fíjate en cómo has programado los bucles:

```
// CREAMOS UN BUCLE DE TIPO FOR PARA DARLE VALOR A LAS VARIABLES DE NUESTRA ESTRUCTURA
for (i=0; i<cantidad; i++)

// IMPRIMIR LOS RESULTADOS DE NUESTRA ESTRUCTURA
for (i=1; i<cantidad; i++)
```

El primero, el que está bien, empieza en `i=0`, mientras que el segundo empieza en `i=1`. Al hacer esto dejas de mostrar el primer elemento de la lista.

Luego, como pequeña mejora, es preferible que cada bucle use su propia variable local

```
// CREAMOS UN BUCLE DE TIPO FOR PARA DARLE VALOR A LAS VARIABLES DE NUESTRA ESTRUCTURA
for (int i=0; i<cantidad; i++)

// IMPRIMIR LOS RESULTADOS DE NUESTRA ESTRUCTURA
for (int i=0; i<cantidad; i++)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, un error tonto muy tonto soy nuevo en esto aun